# Bulk import T-SQL ignoring double quote (")

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using an original script I found a long time ago to create a bulk import of many CSV files into an SQL database. With minor adjustments the script is working for me, but I can't get rid of the double quotes as FIELDQUOTE.

```
DECLARE @Path NVARCHAR(255) = 'D:\TEMP\'
DECLARE @RowTerminator NVARCHAR(5) = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
DECLARE @ColumnTerminator NVARCHAR(5) = CHAR(44)
DECLARE @FieldQuote NVARCHAR(5) = CHAR(34)
--DECLARE @FieldQuote NVARCHAR(5) = '"'

IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[Files_Temporary]', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Files_Temporary];
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Files_Temporary]
(
    [ID] INT
    , [FileName] NVARCHAR(255)
    , [TableName] NVARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Files_Temporary] SELECT 1,       'MyFile.txt',       'MyfileA'
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Files_Temporary] SELECT 2,       'MyFile.txt',       'MyFileB'

DECLARE @Counter INT = 1

WHILE @Counter <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[Files_Temporary])
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Counter is ''' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(5), @Counter) + '''.'

    DECLARE @FileName NVARCHAR(255)
    DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(255)
    DECLARE @Header NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @SQL_Header NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @CreateHeader NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
    DECLARE @SQL_CreateHeader NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT @FileName = [FileName], @TableName = [TableName] FROM [dbo].[Files_Temporary] WHERE [ID] = @Counter

    IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[' + @TableName + ']', 'U') IS NULL
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Creating new table with name ''' + @TableName + '''.'

        IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[Header_Temporary]', 'U') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE [dbo].[Header_Temporary];
        CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Header_Temporary]
        (
            [Header] NVARCHAR(MAX)
        );

        SET @SQL_Header = '
            BULK INSERT [dbo].[Header_Temporary]
            FROM ''' + @Path + @FileName + '''
            WITH
            (
                FIRSTROW = 1,
                LASTROW = 1,
                MAXERRORS = 0,
                FIELDTERMINATOR = ''' + @RowTerminator + ''',
                ROWTERMINATOR = ''' + @RowTerminator + ''',
                FIELDQUOTE = ''' + @FieldQuote + '''
            )'
        EXEC(@SQL_Header)

        SET @Header = (SELECT TOP 1 [Header] FROM [dbo].[Header_Temporary])
        PRINT 'Extracted header ''' + @Header + ''' for table ''' + @TableName + '''.'

        WHILE CHARINDEX(@ColumnTerminator, @Header) > 0
        BEGIN          
            SET @CreateHeader = @CreateHeader + '[' + LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@Header, 1, CHARINDEX(@ColumnTerminator, @Header) - 1))) + '] NVARCHAR(255), '
            SET @Header = SUBSTRING(@Header, CHARINDEX(@ColumnTerminator, @Header) + 1, LEN(@Header)) 
        END
        SET @CreateHeader = @CreateHeader + '[' + @Header + '] NVARCHAR(255)'

        SET @SQL_CreateHeader = 'CREATE TABLE [' + @TableName + '] (' + @CreateHeader + ')'
        EXEC(@SQL_CreateHeader)
    END

    PRINT 'Inserting data from ''' + @FileName + ''' to ''' + @TableName + '''.'
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @SQL = '
        BULK INSERT [dbo].[' + @TableName + ']
        FROM ''' + @Path + @FileName + '''
        WITH
        (
            FIRSTROW = 2,
            MAXERRORS = 0,
            FIELDTERMINATOR = ''' + @ColumnTerminator + ''',
            ROWTERMINATOR = ''' + @RowTerminator + ''',
            FIELDQUOTE = ''' + @FieldQuote + '''            
        )'
    EXEC(@SQL)
    
    SET @Counter = @Counter + 1
END;

IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[Files_Temporary]', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Files_Temporary];

IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[Header_Temporary]', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Header_Temporary];
```

I've declared a variable, but neither the of both give me the correct result. The import is succesfull, but fieldquote is not ignored.

```
DECLARE @FieldQuote NVARCHAR(5) = CHAR(34)
--DECLARE @FieldQuote NVARCHAR(5) = '"'
```

I'm using SSMS V18.10

Comment: This script looks rather clunky tbh but at a guess this looks wrong `FIELDTERMINATOR = ''' + @RowTerminator + ''',` Aside - your SSMS version is irrelevant, the only relevant version is that of SQL Server - `select @@version`

Comment: I have changed the RowTerminator into ColumnTerminator, your right that was a mistake. But I still cannot ignore the double quotes around text. SQL server version = Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-GDR) (KB4583458) - 15.0.2080.9 (X64)

Answer (score -1):

Just add one more setting like below to take care of double quotes.

It will work starting from SQL Server 2017 onwards.

**SQL**

```
...
WITH (
    FORMAT='CSV'
    ...
```

Comment: Thx, for replies, it seems to work fine now.

Comment: Glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please don't forget to mark it as answer.

Comment: This is still not working for me. I have a very basic SQL Query and a rather simple text file with a pretty straight forward table.

Comment: Is it an option to switch to files in XML format? *.csv/txt flat files always have host of problems where column delimiters, column separators, invisible characters like null terminators \0, special characters based on encoding, and line breaks are in the middle of the actual data.
The most reliable format for data feeds is XML enforced by an XSD. An XSD plays a role of a data contract between sender and receiver. It will guarantee proper data format/shape, data types, cardinality, and enforce data quality.

Comment: When I change the character " to something arbitrary like ZZZ the import works fine.

MSSQL Server 2017 - 14.0.3460.9 (X64)

BULK INSERT Command

`BULK INSERT MyTable FROM 'C:Temp.csv' WITH (FORMAT = 'CSV',FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')`

CSV File Data (\t used here to indicate actual tabs in file)

\tThis is some text\t<p>This is some text with a <strong><a href="/info.aspx">URL</a></strong> page.</p>\tSome Text\t7\t0\t0

THE ERROR I GET
`Bulk load failed due to invalid column value in CSV data file C:\Temp.csv in row 1, column 3.`

Comment: Also, when I import it using a connector in C# it allows the quotes no problem. I guess I could try a simple INSERT?

Comment: You can introduce a postprocessing step to remove surrounding double-quotes: `UPDATE tbl SET column = TRIM('"' FROM column)`

Comment: Not sure where I would add that. But, when I was creating the INSERT query, it dawned on me that text fields really need to be enclosed in single quotes. Adding this to the WITH worked for me `, FIELDQUOTE = ''''`